# Urban rides map projects

Tags: urban-riding

Some time ago I read about a project in which bike commuters tracked their paths in order to map then on-line and have a place to see the most frequent routes in their city. Do you know this or other similar projects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strava has a heatmap function you can enable on their route planner.  This will show the more frequently used streets and will vary intensity of color based on popularity.

http://www.strava.com/routes/

Garmin Connect also has a heat map functionality built in to their route planner.

http://connect.garmin.com/course/create

The garmin maps seem to be more effective in heavily used areas like city center and heavily trafficked trails, while strava seems to be a bit better at showing a bit more detail in both city and rural areas.

<strike>May also want to check out Race Shape's heat map, which seems to be a worldwide bike based heat map. Race shape pulls data from strava and ridewithgps.com to create these heat maps. http://raceshape.com/heatmap/</strike>

(Strava has taken over Raceshape and incorporated it in their premium product.)

Comment: That last link is very interesting.

Comment: Yeah, Raceshape looks like the best reference out of the bunch.  It looks pretty nice, despite being a bit crowded with routes, but the color coding is nice to see the more frequented routes.

Comment: Nice options. However I think in Strava or Garmin sites you can not see the maps if you have an account and/or the app installed.

Comment: Yeah, on strava, I don't know that the heat maps are available on mobile. They are in the web app and enabled by the config sidebar, they are not on by default. You may need to be logged in, but do not have to have a premium / paid account.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably thinking of [Rideable - Cycling Visualisations](http://www.rideable.org.au). They have videos showing commutes in Sydney, London and Bristol.

There are other projects such as the [London Cycling Census](http://casa.oobrien.com/traffic/). That compares different vehicle types (bicycles, cars, buses, lorries, etc).

More generally, [The Guardian Datablog](http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog+lifeandstyle/cycling) is a good source for this sort of information.

Answer (score -2):

There's an android app mapmyride which sounds similar to what you want.   It may also be on  the  iPhone

Comment: I don't think MapMyRide does the type of comparison that the OP is asking for.